# Changes to elements of a UIView loaded already

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a `UIView` loaded into a `ViewController` and want to bring change after being loaded (when you click on that `UIView` to change the text color, for example)

```
      @interface CategoryMenu : UIView
    {
        UIImageView *img;
        UIButton *disclosureBtn;
        UIButton *actionView;
        UILabel  *titleLabel;
    }
 @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *img;
 @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *disclosureBtn;
 @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *actionView;
 @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel  *titleLabel;
```

In this way I have loaded this `UIView` in `UIViewController's` where needed.

```
  -(void)showSubviews
{
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.count ; i++)
    {
        NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomMenu" owner:self options:nil];

        CategoryMenu* tempUserView = [nibViews objectAtIndex:0];
        tempUserView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [tempUserView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, x, 280, 50)];
         x+=60;

        tempUserView.tag = i;

        tempUserView.titleLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:i];
        [tempUserView.actionView addTarget:self action:@selector(ExtendedCollapsed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self.view addSubview:tempUserView];
    }
```

Now when you push a `UIView`, besides action itself, I want to change the color of `UILabel` text.

```
-(void)ExtendedCollapsed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"[self.view subviews] = %@",[self.view subviews]);
    UIView *view1 = (UIView *)sender;

    for(UIView *view in [self.view subviews])
    {
        NSLog(@"view = %@ \n ", view);

        if([view isKindOfClass:[CategoryMenu class]])
        {
            if (view.tag == view1.tag)
            {
                NSLog(@"We find the view !!!!");

                CategoryMenu* tempUserView = (CategoryMenu*)view1;

                 NSLog(@"tempUserView = %@ \n ", tempUserView);

                tempUserView.titleLabel.text = @"Text Changed";
                tempUserView.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

                NSLog(@"tempUserView.titleLabel.text = %@",tempUserView.titleLabel.text);

                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"view is not a button");
        }
    }

}
```

Not see any change for the `UIViews` loaded earlier.

Can someone help me with some advice, please?
Thanks

Comment: In showsubviews what are you populating into array?

Comment: nslog for tempUserView is displaying value?

Comment: Yes, this NSLog is displaying info.I wrote this line,because I want to check the address of the UIView.

Comment: Jonathan - I use this array to keep the UILabel text (the name of categories.It an array of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sender parameter in `-(void)ExtendedCollapsed:(id)sender` is your `UIButton *actionView` and not a `CategoryMenu`.

I suppose you have a method in your `CategoryMenu` class implementation that sets your `actionView.tag` to your `CategoryMenu` object `tag` so you can compare them in your loop in `-(void)ExtendedCollapsed:(id)sender` and find the corresponding `CategoryMenu` ?

If that's so, you don't even have to do this, just call `sender.superview` and you'll get the `CategoryMenu` object corresponding to the pressed `actionView`. If `[sender.superview isKindOfClass:[CategoryMenu class]] == TRUE`, you are good to go.

Then, after having changed the color of `tempUserView.titleLabel`, try calling `[tempUserView setNeedsLayout]`.

The method should now look like this :

```
- (void)ExtendedCollapsed:(id)sender {
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        if ([sender.superview isKindOfClass:[CategoryMenu class]]) {
            CategoryMenu *tempUserView = (CategoryMenu *)sender.superview;
            tempUserView.titleLabel.text = @"Text Changed";
            tempUserView.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            [tempUserView setNeedsLayout];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's oky.T hank you very much !